# Preferred way to retrieve the stylesheets used on Wikipedia article

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

Is there a preferred way to retrieve a stylesheet used for a particular article on wikipedia, or are there general stylesheets I can use?

I'm creating a version of the [wiki-game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wiki_Game), and I want the articles to be styled like wikipedia.

Comment: https://mediawiki.org/wiki/Skin:Vector

Comment: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:REST_API/Reference#Get_HTML, https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Wiki_Game?action=render or https://en.wikipedia.org/w/rest.php/v1/page/Wikipedia%3AWiki_Game/html (the two are not indentical but look the same) gives you rendered content with the necessary styles; if you want to replicate the skin as well, you are on your own.